# How could I improve the speed/performance for this problem, Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I saw this challenge on https://www.topcoder.com/ for Beginners. And I really wanted to complete it. I've got so close after so many failures. But I got stuck and don't know what to do no more. Here is what I mean

**Question:**

**Read the input one line at a time and output the current line if and only if you have already read at least 1000 lines greater than the current line and at least 1000 lines less than the current line. (Again, greater than and less than are with respect to the ordering defined by String.compareTo().)**

[Link to the Challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSjYK.png)

**My Solution:**

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    SortedSet<String> linesThatHaveBeenRead = new TreeSet<>();
    int lessThan =0;
    int greaterThan =0;
    
    Iterator<String> itr;
    for (String currentLine = r.readLine(); currentLine != null; currentLine = r.readLine()){
        itr = linesThatHaveBeenRead.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String theCurrentLineInTheSet = itr.next();
            if(theCurrentLineInTheSet.compareTo(currentLine) == -1)++lessThan;
            else if(theCurrentLineInTheSet.compareTo(currentLine) == 1)++greaterThan;
        }
        if(lessThan >= 1000 && greaterThan >= 1000){
            w.println(currentLine);
            lessThan = 0;
            greaterThan =0;
        }
        linesThatHaveBeenRead.add(currentLine);
    
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I think the problem with my solution, is because I'm using nested loops which is making it a lot slower, but I've tried other ways and none worked. At this point I'm stuck. The whole point of this challenge is to make use of the most correct data-structure for this problem.

**GOAL:**

The goal is to use the most efficient data-structure for this problem.

Comment: `point of this challenge is to [use a suitable] data-structure` - so, which data structures *did* you consider? What if two/many lines are identical? How does `I got stuck` manifest?

Comment: Treeset, HashSet, Hashmap, or anything with ordering.

Comment: `anything with ordering` does this apply to `HashSet, Hashmap`? Please do not put additional information that may be useful for more than a minority of readers in comments: edit your post. Is the source cod presented complete? Consider adding code comments: what is the code good for, what are non-obvious statements supposed to achieve. On question all important for performance: do you need to keep more than 2*1000 lines?

Comment: (The *e*-key of the keyboard I'm using lacks reliability.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to present just an accessible refinement of what to do.

```
    public static void
    doIt(java.io.BufferedReader r, java.io.PrintWriter w)
        throws java.io.IOException {
        feedNonExtremes(r, (line) -> { w.println(line);}, 1000, 1000);
    }
   /** Read <code>r</code> one line at a time and
    *   output the current line if and only there already were<br/>
    *    at least <code>nHigh</code> lines greater than the current line <br/>
    *    and at least <code>nLow</code> lines less than the current line.<br/>
    * @param r  to read lines from
    * @param sink   to feed lines to
    * @param nLow   number of lines comparing too small to process
    * @param nHigh  number of lines comparing too great to process
    */
    static void feedNonExtremes(java.io.BufferedReader r,
        Consumer<String> sink, int nLow, int nHigh) {
    // collect nLow+nHigh lines into firstLowHigh; instantiate
    // - a PriorityQueue(firstLowHigh) highest
    // - a PriorityQueue(nLow, (a, b) -> String.compareTo(b, a)) lowest
    // remove() nLow elements from highest and insert each into lowest
    // for each remaining line
    //     if greater than the head of highest
    //         add to highest and remove head
    //     else if smaller than the head of lowest
    //         add to lowest and remove head
    //     else feed to sink
    }
```

Comment: Filling in the *Why/How this accomplishes the task at hand* left as an exercise as much as coding it.

Comment: Same as with your question: hard without *you* indicating where and what your problems are. Tops, I'm not inclined to spoil the learning experience & fun.

Comment: `don't get [… how PriorityQueue] would help` To not process lines among *the highest* seen so far, compare it to the lowest from *the highest* (constant amortised time with any self-respecting priority queue): if greater, do not process, but add to *the highest* (O(log(k)) time) and remove that lowest from *the highest*(O(log(k)) time, again). Same for lowest; iff there are enough lines both greater and smaller, process (print - no PriorityQueue here). Instantiating a decent priority queue from a collection is faster (O(n)) than an ordered set - which would incorrectly ignore repeated lines.

Comment: `I don't get why PriorityQueue is faster than Treeset` it *can* implement relevant operations faster because it does not need to support as many different ones. `I've tried so many data-structures` If you show your attempts, including what makes you think it doesn't work (and why), members of this community might help you.

Comment: Aha! wow makes sense, I will give one more shot, If i'm not able to get, what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Made you a little example with Binary search, now in Java code. It will only use Binary search when newLine is within limits of the sorting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create random lines
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        Random rn = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            int lenght = rn.nextInt(100);
            char[] newString = new char[lenght];
            for (int j = 0; j < lenght; j++) {
                newString[j] = (char) rn.nextInt(255);
            }

            lines.add(new String(newString));
        }

        // Here starts logic
        ArrayList<String> lowerCompared = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> higherCompared = new ArrayList<String>();
        int lowBoundry = 1000, highBoundry = 1000;

        int k = 0;
        int firstLimit = Math.min(lowBoundry, highBoundry);

        // first x lines sorter equal
        for (; k < firstLimit; k++) {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(lowerCompared, lines.get(k));
            if (index < 0)
                index = ~index;
            lowerCompared.add(index, lines.get(k));
            higherCompared.add(index, lines.get(k));
        }

        for (; k < lines.size(); k++) {
            String newLine = lines.get(k);
            boolean lowBS = newLine.compareTo(lowerCompared.get(lowBoundry - 1)) < 0;
            boolean highBS = newLine.compareTo(higherCompared.get(0)) > 0;
            if (lowerCompared.size() == lowBoundry && higherCompared.size() == highBoundry && !lowBS && !highBS) {
                System.out.println("Time to print: " + newLine);
                continue;
            }
            if (lowBS) {
                int lowerIndex = Collections.binarySearch(lowerCompared, newLine);
                if (lowerIndex < 0)
                    lowerIndex = ~lowerIndex;

                lowerCompared.add(lowerIndex, newLine);
                if (lowerCompared.size() > lowBoundry)
                    lowerCompared.remove(lowBoundry);

            }
            if (highBS) {
                int higherIndex = Collections.binarySearch(higherCompared, newLine);
                if (higherIndex < 0)
                    higherIndex = ~higherIndex;

                higherCompared.add(higherIndex, newLine);
                if (higherCompared.size() > highBoundry)
                    higherCompared.remove(0);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its close to the same. I believe it has also the list with binarysearch. I did not have jaca environnent on my laptop..

Comment: https://repl.it/ has online environment for any coding language also why are you doing "compared.BinarySearch(newLine)? isn't the "compared list" already empty"? I'm trying to translate this code to java

Comment: Good point, will do next time. I am creating a new sortedlist which is filled by each newline. With each newline i check where its index is. In relarion to lines added already..

Comment: After Translating the code to java, unfortunately the code didn't pass the challenge, its not efficient, or slow. I think there is a much faster way around Treesets but I'm not strong with sets.

Comment: Binary searches are fast. How do you get to your conclusion? To my knowledge you have same performance with treeset.

Comment: I just realized, you do not have to sort all, only compare the current with min1000. I can have a look on monday.

Comment: @markHenry Just so you know, it is considered rude on Stack Overflow to demand a solution urgently or at a specific time (even more so on weekends). It makes it seem like you consider your question to be more important than the questions of other users.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I apologize about that, Its just I'm extremely concerned about the solution

Comment: @Aldert Its not working, I translated it to Java, Maybe I didn't do it properly. but could u, please provide a java version with how I tested it, like "do it" function? Have you updated it from last timee?

Comment: @Aldert Yeah I tried it again, I dont seem to quite succesfully translate this code to java as you may see it working C#, Like I did trasnlate it to Java, but its not working(I didn't get anything snytax errors) but its some how running out of memory

Comment: I have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement binary search and also need to handle duplicates.

I've done some code sample here which does what you want ( may contains bugs).

```
public class CheckRead1000 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // generate strings in revert order to get the worse case
        List<String> aaa = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 50000; i > 0; i--) {
            aaa.add("some string 123456789" + i);
        }

        // fast solution
        ArrayList<String> sortedLines = new ArrayList<>();
        long st1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (String a : aaa) {
            checkIfRead1000MoreAndLess(sortedLines, a);
        }

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - st1);

        // doIt solution
        TreeSet<String> linesThatHaveBeenRead = new TreeSet<>();
        long st2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (String a : aaa) {
            doIt(linesThatHaveBeenRead, a);
        }

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - st2);
    }

    // solution doIt
    public static void doIt(SortedSet<String> linesThatHaveBeenRead, String currentLine) {

        int lessThan = 0;
        int greaterThan = 0;

        Iterator<String>  itr = linesThatHaveBeenRead.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String theCurrentLineInTheSet = itr.next();
            if (theCurrentLineInTheSet.compareTo(currentLine) == -1) ++lessThan;
            else if (theCurrentLineInTheSet.compareTo(currentLine) == 1) ++greaterThan;
        }

        if (lessThan >= 1000 && greaterThan >= 1000) {
            // System.out.println(currentLine);
            lessThan = 0;
            greaterThan = 0;
        }

        linesThatHaveBeenRead.add(currentLine);
    }

    // will return if we have read more at least 1000 string more and less then our string
    private static boolean checkIfRead1000MoreAndLess(List<String> sortedLines, String newLine) {
        //adding string to list and calculating its index and the last search range
        int indexes[] = addNewString(sortedLines, newLine);
        int index = indexes[0]; // index of element
        int low = indexes[1];
        int high = indexes[2];

        //we need to check if this string already was in list for instance
        // 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7   for 5  we need to count 'less' as 4 and 'more' is 2
        int highIndex = index;

        for (int i = highIndex + 1; i < high; i++) {
            if (sortedLines.get(i).equals(newLine)) {
                highIndex++;
            } else {
                //no more duplicates
                break;
            }
        }

        int lowIndex = index;

        for (int i = lowIndex - 1; i > low; i--) {
            if (sortedLines.get(i).equals(newLine)) {
                lowIndex--;
            } else {
                //no more duplicates
                break;
            }
        }

        // just calculating how many we did read more and less
        if (sortedLines.size() - highIndex - 1 > 1000 && lowIndex > 1000) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // simple binary search will insert string and return its index and ranges in sorted list
    // first int is index,
    // second int is start of range - will be used to find duplicates,
    // third int  is end of range - will be used to find duplicates,
    private static int[] addNewString(List<String> sortedLines, String newLine) {
        if (sortedLines.isEmpty()) {
            sortedLines.add(newLine);
            return new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        }

        // int index = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int low = 0;
        int high = sortedLines.size() - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (sortedLines.get(mid).compareTo(newLine) < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if (sortedLines.get(mid).compareTo(newLine) > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else if (sortedLines.get(mid).compareTo(newLine) == 0) {
                // index = mid;
                break;
            }

            if (low > high) {
                mid = low;
            }
        }

        if (mid == sortedLines.size()) {
            sortedLines.add(newLine);
        } else {
            sortedLines.add(mid, newLine);
        }

        return new int[]{mid, low, high};
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the finishing the code. Its slow and not efficient.

Comment: I've tried too and it is more than 100 times faster than your sample ;-)

Comment: why is it upvoted? can u try converting that to my test case, instead of having mutiple functions, maybe you're right? I'm not sure. have you tried testing your code for 1 million text? or 500k or 100k?

Comment: No, I  did convert your solution to my test class. You may run the code above and will see difference. On 50k my solution takes 200ms your solution ~45sec.

Comment: but how do I make all of your code into one function only instead of mutiple stuff